# Get a 404 error with simple spring-data-rest project

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to configure spring-data-rest over my spring-mvc project, but every time I enter the url to access json of my repository-info - it returns 404. Looks like it doesn't see my spring-data-rest annotation/dependency at all

Here is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.konan</groupId>
<artifactId>libsupport</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>LibSupport</name>
<description>Library Support System</description>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/lib-support</path>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "books", collectionResourceRel = "books")
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> { 

}
```

And config classes:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{JPAConfig.class,};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = BookRepository.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class JPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean");

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("entities.scan"));

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }


    private Map<String, String> hibernateProperties() {
        Map<String, String> hibernateProperties = new HashMap<>();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hb.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hb.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hb.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("hb.format_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", environment.getProperty("hb.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BookController.class, BookService.class})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

So I enter the next URL "http://localhost:8080/lib-support/books"
[and have this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcylg.png)

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing @EnableJpaRepositories in your WebConfig.

Comment: 1. config based on packages ? or class names ? 2. Enable JPA repository 3. Why `lib-support` in request url ? 4. Web.xml is configured base url ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri 
1)Config based on packages
2)Here is this annotation from JpaConfig, I just missed to attach it to the question
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = BookRepository.class)`
3) I mention it in pom.xml 
`<configuration>
                    <path>/lib-support</path>
</configuration>`

Comment: @Milan
I didn't include JpaConfig.class to the question, here I have `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = BookRepository.class)`, there everything is alright


My project works as Spring MVC, but fails as Spring-Data-Rest (404)

Comment: what about http://localhost:8080/lib-support/ ? it also returns 404?

Comment: @Matias Elorriaga
404 too, but I think that should be like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okey guys, I found out what the problem was. I created reporitories classes not for all entity classes, as a result - Spring wasn't able to generate appropriate links for relative entities. For example I have `Book` entity, that have `OneToMany` mapping to `BookCopy` entity class, but `BookCopyRepository` was not exist.

Comment: You should mark your answer to show the questions has been resolved

Comment: Do we need to extend the relative repositories with `JpaRepository` or do we need to do the whole `@RepositoryRestResource` thing?